# Can't Install Xubuntu to Asus eee PC 901

Tags: installation, usb, xubuntu, asus

I can’t install xubuntu from usb. I did not make any changes when I was in usb disc creation section. It says it was 100% complete. I restart and make changes from bios on boot section. Save it. Ok. I restart again. Nothing. It says press ESC to boot (in 10 seconds). I press it, but it goes to windows anyway. Usb led light is blinking during restart, so it tries to read it. When I try to install xubuntu from CD it says:

> This kernal requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 cpu. Unable to boot – please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.

I used this same installation cd to my other computer fujitsu-siemens amilo 1520.
It does work very well there.

My new laptop is: Asus Eee PC 901
Procesor: Intel Atom N270

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Well the problem is that your CPU doesn’t support 64bit OS. So you need to download the 32bit version instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have downloaded an amd64 ISO instead of an i386 ISO. Please download the Xubuntu i386 ISO from  http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.04.1/release/xubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso (12.04.1) or http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/12.10/release/xubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso (12.10)